# Properly Authorizing/Protecting Signalr Core Hub

Tags: blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, microsoft.identity.web

I am trying to setup Blazor Server with a Signal R Core hub using Azure SignalR Services.

In general the Blazor app is working fine and is using Azure SignalR Services.

The Signal R Core Hub will work if I decorate it using [AllowAnonymous]. If I remove the [AllowAnonymous] the Signalr R Core client's HubConnection StartAsync gives a variety of errors depending on what I adjust in startup.cs. Using Fiddler I can tell the StartAsync attempts to retrieve a token from login.microsoftonline.com.

I don't understand why the currently logged in and authorized isn't being used.

Even when I use [AllowAnonymous] the Signalr R Hub will pickup the the username.

Here is the code for the Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace ServerApp.Services.NotificationHub
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class BlazorChatHub : Hub
    {
        public const string HubUrl = "/coaching";

        private ILogger<BlazorChatHub> _logger;

        public BlazorChatHub(ILogger<BlazorChatHub> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        
        public async Task Broadcast(string username, string message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Broadcast: {username} : {message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast", username, message);
        }

        
        public async Task Send(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", message);
        }

        
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"SendMessage: {user} : {message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{Context.ConnectionId} connected");

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Disconnected {e?.Message} {Context.ConnectionId}");                
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Blazor page where the Hub is opened. _hubConnection.StartAsync() fails if I remove the [AllowAnonymous] from the Hub shown above.

```
// Create the chat client
string baseUrl = navigationManager.BaseUri;

_hubUrl = baseUrl.TrimEnd('/') + BlazorChatHub.HubUrl;
    
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_hubUrl)
    .Build();

_hubConnection.On<string, string>("Broadcast", BroadcastMessage);

await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

From Startup.cs, I believe this is where the problem may originate:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);                
        })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() //initialScopes
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Almost as if the Hub is considered a downstreamapi, when it is actually on the same Blazor Server app. Why is Blazor Server trying to go to login.microsoftonline.com to re-authenticate for "localhost/coaching/negotiate"?

Comment: Look at your code, it should be simple official sample code, which document you refer to to test, so that we can test locally, so that we can help you faster.

Comment: Unfortunately what I am trying to do is add SignalR to an existing application so pulling out a mock project is not really possible. I do understand why you would want the sample project. Any insights where to look for why a strongly typed SignalR Hub is trying to re-authenticate to login.microsoftonline.com?